# How to override zk.Widget method for only concrete object?

Tags: zk, zul

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function move() {
      var pMeter = zk.Widget.$('$curr_met');
      // TODO override pMeter method here
    }
</script>

<progressmeter id="curr_met" value="0" width="280px" />
```

**I want to override _fixImgWidth for pMeter object. Is it possible ?**

Answer (score 1):

This answer is [given at ZK forum](http://forum.zkoss.org/question/100487/how-to-override-zkwidget-method-for-only-concrete-object/#100491) by cor3000 :
I'm only adding this answer for the future readers.

> yes it is possible. Like with any JS object you can override methods
>   by replacing them. (This is not ZK specific.)
>
> ```
> var oldMethod = pMeter._fixImgWidth;
> pMeter._fixImgWidth = function(){
>   // your implementation
>   // or call original method
>   oldMethod.apply(this, arguments)
> }
> ```
>
> However there are some supporting functions in ZK to make this simpler
>   from both ZUL or java code (see documentation links below):
>
> [Override in zul
>   file](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Client-side_Reference/General_Control/Widget_Customization#Override_a_Widget_Method)
>
> [Override using the java API (same
>   page)](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Client-side_Reference/General_Control/Widget_Customization#Override_a_Widget_Method_in_Java)
>
> In case you just want to change the animation-speed follow [this
>   example](http://zkfiddle.org/sample/1o8q7mh/1-progessmeter-set-animation-speed)
>   using the ca:animation-speed client/attribute  (7.0.3+):